# selecting parent's second sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My markup is somthing like this. I need to grab the div's content and my current context is the img tag.

```
<td>
  <IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Selected align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif">
</td>

<td>
</td>

<td>
 <div> Some text </div>
</td>
```

I am trying to select the parent td of the IMG and then select the second sibling of the parent td in oder to get to the div. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help

```
$("IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif'].parent('td').nextAll().eq(1)").hide();
```

Comment: This is why syntax highlighting is useful.

Comment: If you use a proper text editor, you will find this kind of syntax errors a lot easier. And why don't hou give the an ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get more success with this

```
$("IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif']").parent('td').nextAll().eq(1).hide();
```

rather than

```
$("IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif'].parent('td').nextAll().eq(1)").hide();
```